# Getting the FileNotFoundException in the NLP project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

I start working on a NLP project as beginner and I had add a `en-sent.bin` file to run a method provided below,

```
public static void SentenceDetect() {

        try {

            String paragraph = "Hi. How are you? This is Mike.";

            // always start with a model, a model is learned from training data
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-sent.bin");
            SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(is);
            SentenceDetectorME sdetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);

            String sentences[] = sdetector.sentDetect(paragraph);

            System.out.println(sentences[0]);
            System.out.println(sentences[1]);
            is.close();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have the following error comes in the `Intellij`,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: en-sent.bin (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.nlp.processor.MyNlp.SentenceDetect(MyNlp.java:22)
    at com.nlp.processor.MyNlp.main(MyNlp.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

The issue is I put the `en-sent.bin` in the project, figure below.

[image]

I added the files from Intellij -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Selected over the Project SDK and added the files using (+) sign as `JAR or Directories`. Figure below.

[image]

How to solve this `FileNotFoundException` in the project ?

Updated figure of the project:

[image]

Comment: My guess is, `en-sent.bin` is no longer a "file", but is an embedded resource (contained within the application context/jar), try using `Class#getResourceAsStream` instead

Comment: Not working `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: in must not be null!` and get this error in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the en-sent.bin parallel to src folder, It should work.

Or, provide absolute path - instead of relative path.

Comment: It still doesn't work , I provided a updated figure of the project.

Comment: You have put inside libs, I had mentioned it should be parallel to src. which means your NlpProcessor project should contain following immediately inside it - .idea, libs, src, en-sent.bin, target

Comment: plus, it has nothing to do with NLP - its a file reading issue. Please reframe your question Title.